# Is there a way to create an intermediate output from Sphinx extensions?

Tags: documentation, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

When sphinx processes an rst to html conversion is there a way to see an intermediate format after extensions have been processed?

I am looking for an intermediate rst file that is generated after sphinx extensions were run.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the "ReST Builder" extension: https://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib-restbuilder/.

There's not much to say; the extension takes reST as input and outputs ...drumroll... reST!

Quote:

> This extension is in particular useful to use in combination with the autodoc extension. In this combination, autodoc generates the documentation based on docstrings, and restbuilder outputs the result are reStructuredText (.rst) files. The resulting files can be fed to any reST parser, for example, they can be automatically uploaded to the GitHub wiki of a project.