# Examine generated ReST from sphinx extension

Tags: python-sphinx

I'm using a Sphinx extension ([this one](https://github.com/click-contrib/sphinx-click/blob/master/sphinx_click/ext.py#L133)) which generates some ReST markup dynamically. Sphinx uses that ReST to generate html documentation.

I want to examine and run doctests on the generated ReST markup. Normally I use

```
sphinx-build -E -b html docs dist/docs
```

to generate the html output, but there is no `rst` "builder" equivalent to the `html` one.

How can I examine the generated ReST markup?

Comment: Perhaps this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19523151/407651

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Sphinx extension [`sphinx.ext.doctest`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/doctest.html), following its syntax and markup.

Then run `make doctest` to run the doctests.

**Update**

In response to your comments and taking the suggestion from @mzjn, it sounds like you want to generate an intermediate set of documentation that is in reStructuredText. The Sphinx extension [restbuilder](https://pythonhosted.org/sphinxcontrib-restbuilder/) might be want you seek.

From that point, `make doctest` might be want you want.

Comment: I'm using [docshtest](https://github.com/vaab/docshtest/) not only vanilla `sphinx.ext.doctest` because I want to test shell demos. I've found a workaround, but for future reference, Is it possible to examine the generated rst from an extension?

Comment: What do you mean "examine"? When I examine a file, I open it in an editor and look at it, and I assume you can do that. Maybe you mean something else?

Comment: Opening it in a file is what I mean. The link in my question shows that extension generates some rst, but I don't think it's ever written to a file, so I don't know how to look at it in my editor (or run `docshtest` on it).